# Merge maps in Golang concurrently

Tags: dictionary, go, concurrency, channel

I am trying to merge many maps concurrently.
I want to pop two maps from a channel, merge these two maps and send the merged map back to same channel until merging maps is finished.

The bigger picture is that I produce maps concurrently and I want to start merging maps as soon as there are two available. In the end I want to have one merged map of all produced maps.

I want to make sth like this:

```
func processMaps(c1 chan map[string]int) {
    for map1 := range c1 {
        map2 := <-c1
        mergedMap := mergeMaps(map1, map2)
        c1 <- mergedMap
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: From the approach you outlined, you'd probably be creating many maps (which is expensive!) and copying the keys and values over and over. I'd suggest you go for a simpler solution, keeping a map in the upper scope of the function, as the answer suggests; as new maps come in merge the two. Sure, this is not very concurrent, but other solutions would probably be more expensive, or require mutexes. If you're _really_ dead set on setting the values concurrently, you can give [sync.Map](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Map) a shot - [but you probably don't need it](https://youtu.be/C1EtfDnsdDs).

Answer (score 1):

Start with an empty map and merge any maps received on the channel to the map:

```
merged := make(make[string]int)
for m := range c {
    for k, v := range m {
       merged[k] = v
    }
}
```

The loop exits when channel `c` is closed.  The map `merged` is the merge of all maps received on `c`.

Use variable to refer to the merged map instead of sending the merged map back to the channel.  Sending the merged map back to the channel makes the end condition more complicated without increasing concurrency.